# .val has no effect, and also .append has no effect

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

My code:

```
       $.ajax({
            url: "{{URL::to('/announcement/get/fields')}}",
            type: "post",
            data: {id:id},
            success: function (response) {

                this.title = "n/a";
                this.body = "n/a";

                var self = this;

               $.each( response, function( key, value ) {
                 self.title = response['aTitle'];
                 self.body = response['aBody'];
                });

               $('#announcementEditTitle').val(this.title);
               $('#announcementEditBody').append(this.body);
               // CKEDITOR.instances[editEditor].insertText(this.body);
               console.log(this.title);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
            }


        });
```

response returns an array like this:

```
aTitle: value

aBody: announcement content
```

There is a `SELECT` option in the form and once the user clicks on an announcement title, the values of that announcement should be inserted into the announcement title field and announcement body.

Value was working for few moments but somehow I broke it, and append wasn't working at all.

For the body `#announcementEditBody` I have a `textarea` with [CKeditor](https://ckeditor.com/) on it.

if I do `<textarea>Some text</textarea>` "Some text" will show in the `ckeditor` but if I append it with jquery nothing will show.

#### UPDATE

`$('#announcementEditTitle')` returns length 0, but `this.title` returns the length of the title so the variable isn't empty

#### UPDATE 2

I just noticed that I did not need the .each, my bad, so I did this

```
$("#announcementEditTitle").val(response['aTitle']);
$('#announcementEditBody').append(response['aBody']);
```

But it still doesn't work, yet if I do `console.log(response['aTitle']);` it works.

Fixed the title, but the body still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you getting proper data in variables key and value. Use those to set self.Title and self.body

Comment: @Amit yes, I get proper values, I used console.log to test, since console.log displays it properly, why wouldn't .val and .append? Which are in the same scope

Comment: Do `$('#announcementEditTitle')` and `$('#announcementEditBody')` return anything (`length`) perhaps this is all happening before the DOM has been fully rendered.

Comment: If the `#announcementEditBody` `textarea` is not a CKEditor form (try taking CKEditor off of it), do things work as you expect? It may be that CKEditor manipulates the DOM, or otherwise enforces a different API for setting text, such that changing the value of the original elements no longer works.

Comment: Another one. If announcementEditTitle is an input field, use .val() otherwise use .html() and .text()

Comment: @FrancisDucharme I used `console.log($('#announcementEditTitle').length);` and their length is 0.

Comment: @Amit I already use .val... for title, it doesn't work, text neither, and their length is 0... why

Comment: Are these elements available on page before your code executes.

Comment: Looking at your code, do you know what you're doing? You're getting a result set of several titles/messages, iterate them but store them all in the same variable? And then you target ALL elements with ID #announcementEditTitle (I'm assuming there are supposed to be several)

Comment: @SlapY there is only one of each ID, not more, and how do I store all of them in same variable? one is `this.title` and one is `this.body` - They display right in console.log so why would the issue be the `.each` if console.log displays them?

Comment: @Amit Yes, it is a modal, I open the modal by clicking on "Edit", I select the announcement name and thats when ajax fires, announcement title is displayed in console same as body, same as variables length, but, .val and .append do nothing.

Comment: Can you include html for modal here as well? announcementEditTitle is a div or input element. For div, use .html()

Comment: @Amit It is an input

Comment: @Dano I don't know what you're trying to do. Is the response an array of arrays? Does it contain several announcements or just one? If it just contains one, what do you need the each-Loop for? If it's several, you need to move the other lines inside of the each and can not use IDs.

Comment: By the way if $('#announcementEditTitle').length is 0, there's your answer.

Comment: @SlapY I just noticed that I did not need the .each, updated my first post, but still it doesn't work, and also, can you explain why the length of that would be 0 if the variable's length is not 0? I really don't understand.

Comment: @Dano of course you did. However. jQuery can't find the element with ID announcementEditTitle. Is it present? Is it really an ID (#) or is it a class (.) ?

Comment: @SlapY I return the result as array from laravel and I  tought that I have to iterate over it in jquery.. anyway, fixed the title but the textarea is still not working `<textarea name="editor2" class="form-control" id="announcementEditBody" rows="3" placeholder="Enter ..."></textarea>` neither .val, .text or .append work on it.

Comment: Then try .html()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You

- don't need the each()
- probably targeted #announcementEditTitle wrongly (maybe not an ID but a class? spelling?)
- are using the wrong jQuery method to fill the Body, use val (or try text/html, but it should be val)

Comment: Removed the each, title is working now but I can't insert into textarea, it is CKEDITOR and `CKEDITOR.instances.editor2.setData(response['aBody']);` doesn't work, I get `Unable to get property 'setData' of undefined or null reference`

Comment: Mhmm okay not very familliar with CKEditor, another answer suggests this syntax: CKEDITOR.instances["editor2"].setData(response['aBody']); Otherwise you might want to ask a new question specific to setting the body of CKEditor! :)